# google/zx tar Gives "No such file or directory"

Tags: google-zx

I am using google/zx to create a simple backup script using tar. The code I'm using to generate the tar command looks like this:

```js
  const tarCommandString = `tar czf "${absoluteBackupFile}" -P "${folder}"`;
  const tarCommand = await $`${tarCommandString}`.exitCode;
```

I keep getting the following error `/usr/bin/bash: line 1: tar czf "/home/syssu/backup/home-syssu-testToBackup/1692150304.tar.gz" -P "/home/syssu/testToBackup": No such file or directory`.

However I can literally take that command `tar czf "/home/syssu/backup/home-syssu-testToBackup/1692150304.tar.gz" -P "/home/syssu/testToBackup"` and manually run it without any issue.

Comment: Any chance it runs it without `PATH`, in other words, what if you specify the full path to `tar` instead?

Comment: I was thinking maybe it could not find tar as well, but if I run `which tar` it finds it at `/usr/bin/tar`. I also changed the command from `tar` to `/usr/bin/tar` but that did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/google/zx#command-) says:

> Everything passed through ${...} will be automatically escaped and quoted.

In other words

```
$`${tarCommandString}`
```

here entire `tarCommandString` is treated as a single command.

You should

```
await $`tar czf "${absoluteBackupFile}" -P "${folder}"`
```

instead.

Comment: Ah I think what the problem is, is that I have the double quotes around `"${absoluteBackupFile}" ` and `"${folder}"`?

Comment: OK, I think I understand now, but it seems weird. I see this reported issue someone has a workaround: https://github.com/google/zx/issues/126